# Ionic starter project aws_user_pools_id is not defined error

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using the ionic-team Amazon starter project and when i go through the steps and try to log into the project i get this error

```
ReferenceError: aws_user_pools_id is not defined
    at Cognito.webpackJsonp.199.Cognito.getUserPool (aws.cognito.ts:25)
    at Cognito.webpackJsonp.199.Cognito.makeUser (aws.cognito.ts:51)
    at user.ts:32
    at new t (polyfills.js:3)
    at User.webpackJsonp.40.User.login (user.ts:31)
    at LoginPage.webpackJsonp.39.LoginPage.login (login.ts:38)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (LoginPage.html:5)
    at handleEvent (core.es5.js:11914)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13206)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.es5.js:12794)
```

and im not sure what to do. Can someone help?

Comment: It might help to post the login code (with username and password changed of course).

Comment: Login code? I have just used the ionic starter project and have not had anything to do with writing that code